Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.ee when validating plug-ins
I inherited an Eclipse RCP application (org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application) from my colleague.
When I click on Launch an Eclipse application in the MyApp.product overview panel, I get many warnings when validating my plug-ins like these:

If I click on Continue I get a launch error:

The application could not start

And this is the log:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2024-04-12 12:25:03.832
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2006)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-04-12 12:25:03.832
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.5.200.v20240209-1053.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2024-04-12 12:25:03.847
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-04-12 12:25:03.847
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)

I googled and found a possible solution but clicking on Run configurations > Plug-ins > Add required plug-ins won't fix the issue. Another solution, which won't work, is here.
This is the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, if you need it:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyBundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.myapp;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
  swing2swt.jar
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.myapp.managers.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: mycompany
Export-Package: com.mycompany.mybundle.log.log4j,
  com.mycompany.myapp.data,
  com.mycompany.myapp.dialogs,
  com.mycompany.myapp.handlers,
  com.mycompany.myapp.listeners,
  com.mycompany.myapp.managers,
  com.mycompany.myapp.parts,
  com.mycompany.myapp.providers,
  com.mycompany.myapp.table,
  com.mycompany.myapp.utils,
  com.mycompany.myapp.utils.filesystem,
  com.mycompany.myapp.views
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.2",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 ca.odell.glazedlists;bundle-version="1.9.0",
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.ui;bundle-version="2.13.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi;bundle-version="2.14.0",
 com.mycompany.tmlibrary,
 com.mycompany.applicationManager;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.draw2d,
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.apache.poi,
 org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.12.0",
 org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen;bundle-version="1.1.6"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: com.mycompany.application.configurations,
 com.mycompany.tmlibrary.configuration,
 com.mycompany.tmlibrary.files,
 com.mycompany.tmlibrary.files.zte,
 com.mycompany.tmlibrary.utils,
 com.mycompany.tool.utils,
 com.mycompany.myapp.managers,
 javax.annotation;version="1.0.0",
 javax.inject;version="1.0.0",
 org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar;version="1.6.0",
 org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip;version="1.6.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services.events,
 org.eclipse.equinox.app;version="1.1.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8

How can I solve?

Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17)) means you must use at least Java 17. Current Eclipse releases require a minimum of Java 17.

@greg-449 If I browse to com.mycompany.myapp > JRE System Library in Eclipse explorer, it says "JavaSE-1.8", which means I am using Java 8. Upgrading to Java 17 will fix, right?

You will also need to change the Run Configuration to use Java 17 (or later)

@greg-449 What about the other warnings such as: "Missing constraint Import Package"?

That means a plugin has asked to import a java package but the system cannot find any plugin that exports that package or it found the package but the version was not in the required range. So your target platform is probably missing things.
